# Accessing Geocoder Result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying out the geocoder gem and looking to acceess the viewport results.

Being new to Ruby is there a better way to access the result.

```
result = Geocoder.search("New York, NY").map(&:geometry)
north_east_lat = result[0]["viewport"]["northeast"]["lat"]
north_east_lng = result[0]["viewport"]["northeast"]["lng"]
```

While this does work it looks ugly and brittle

Any advise on making this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I see, `geometry` data is just a simple `Hash`.  If you don't like the way you have to access values by ["key"] at multiple levels, you can convert Hash to OpenStruct.

```rb
require 'ostruct'

result = Geocoder.search("New York, NY").first
# singleton class http://www.devalot.com/articles/2008/09/ruby-singleton
class << result
  def ostructic_geometry
    ostructly_deep self.geometry
  end

  private
    def ostructly_deep(hash)
      root = OpenStruct.new

      # http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-marshal_load
      # -- from the user comment at the bottom --
      # In the marchal_load() example, the Hash should have symbols as keys:
      # hash = { :time => Time.now, :title => 'Birthday Party' }
      load_data = hash.each_pair.inject({}) do |all, (key, value)|
        value = ostructly_deep(value) if value.is_a?(Hash)
        all[key.to_sym] = value # keys need to be symbols to load
        all
      end

      root.marshal_load load_data
      root
    end
end

now_you_can_call_value_from_member_geometry = result.ostructic_geometry
now_you_can_call_value_from_member_geometry.bounds.northeast.lat # => 40.9152414
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Geocoder::Result methods to access to that data, for example:

result[0].city
result[0].latitud

see all the methods with, result[0].methods

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it. [`geometry`](http://rdoc.info/gems/geocoder/Geocoder/Result/Google%3ageometry) is only defined on a Google Maps API result, since it's a very Google-specific field: it not only contains the coordinates (which geocoder already extracts), but also the `location_type`, `viewport`, and `bounds`, which aren't considered to fall within geocoder's standard use case: `location_type` has to do with the precision of the result, `viewport` is exclusively about how Google "recommends" that we display this result on a visual map, and `bounds` is a bounding box for the entire city/state/whatever. While each is relevant in a very particular use case, most people using geocoder don't need them, so the developer doesn't take responsibility for them and instead exposes the fields directly. So, if you want a clean way to access these fields, you'll have to build it yourself.

If you're using the viewport feature often, it might be worth making your own `Viewport` class to represent this data, then either wrapping the expression manually (like `Viewport.from_geometry(result.geometry)`) or patching your own `viewport` method into `Geocoder::Result::Google`. Your call.